# Sending array using json_encode via body onload is not working for me

Tags: php, javascript, json

I want to send array using `json_encode` via body onload. But this not work for me.
I have echo it in php and I get the array but when I send to a function using body onload it did not work.

**Here is my php**

```
foreach ($row as $r) {

$thestar[] = $r['id'];
$yes= json_encode($thestar);     


  }

<body onload =xxx(<?php echo $yes ?>);>
```

Comment: What happens? What do you see in the generated source?

Comment: can you show us the value of $yes that you are passing to the js function?

Comment: Where do you want to send it?

Comment: Well, It make whole function stop working. I have test by using alert(); I get nothing also.

Comment: I get something like this  ["650","651"]

Comment: Shouldn't you `json_encode` the array outside the `foreach`?

Comment: I´m sending to a function in another javascript document.

Comment: @PoramatFin Why do you have `<body onload =xxx(<?php echo $yes ?>);>` inside `()`? If anything you should probably be doing something like `<body onload ="<?php echo $yes ?>;">` or `<body onload =\"<?php echo $yes ?>;\">` or `<body onload ='<?php echo $yes ?>;'>`

Comment: Khalid Dabjan   i have test it, and i get the message   undefined.

Comment: Hei  Fred -ii-   I will send it to a function call xxx

Comment: @PoramatFin It still needs to be in quotes.

Comment: @PoramatFin Then wrap it inside a function called (for example, test) and then use `<body onload ='<?php $test(); ?>'>` that should theoretically work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what are you talking about? that syntax makes no sense, Poamat the json_encode should be outside the foreach, change that and then try EJTH's answer

Comment: @koala_dev Great then, so you should have made a comment/answer to that affect. I'm no PRO, but hey.... at least I tried ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really put it inside a script tag instead.:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
var xxxParams = <?=json_encode($arr);?>;
</script>
<body onload="xxx(xxxParams);">
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I did not know before that body onload can not have direct Json encode, thanks :)